# AudioKit v5 Synth: change underlying waveform(s)

Tags: audiokit

Im trying to alter the Wave form of the new v5 Synth, I can alter any number of the parameters of masterVolume , pitch, filterRes and cutoff but acquiring and setting the waves of the underlying voices is a lot more complex than just triggering these surface level functions.

I notice the Synth .swift class has the following member:

```
public private(set) var internalAU: AudioUnitType?
```

when I drill down into that I find a class called SynthAudioUnit

which has the following function:

```
public override func createDSP() -> DSPRef {
    return akSynthCreateDSP()
}
```

Seemingly a .swift wrapper for a deeper function in SynthDSP.mm:

```
DSPRef akSynthCreateDSP() {
return new SynthDSP();
```

}
...SynthDSP appears to have a member var: CoreSynth, is CoreSynth where I have to make alterations to the waveforms?, Is it necessary to make custom versions of SynthDSP.mm for this, in the same fashion as in the office hours #3 video: https://audiokitpro.com/officehours-3/
....
Or is there an easier way of doing what I want?

Comment: Update: CoreAudio has a member var : SynthVoice, a modified version of this can be used to make custom synth voices and change the waveform fairly easily, obviously as long as all the appropriate headers are updated e.t.c, that pretty much does what I was trying to get at with this question. Just one other thing - if you haven't seen those office hours videos and you are learning AudioKit, I recommend that you do so at your earliest convenience - there is info in there you could spend absolutely ages trying to find