# AudioKit v5 - How do I change the waveform of a DunneAudioKit Synth?

Tags: swift, audiokit, waveform, synth

I am trying to build a simple synthesizer that will play a `MIDINoteNumber` using the DunneAudioKit `Synth` function `.play(noteNumber:, velocity:)` when a button is pressed.

I am able to produce sound and change a few parameters of the `Synth` instance (`attackDuration`, `decayDuration`, `sustainLevel`, `releaseDuration`, etc.), but I do not know how I can change the waveform of the `Synth` instance itself.

I would like to be able to use `.sine`, `.square`, and `.sawtooth` tables as well as their combinations. Ideally, I would be able to have a sub oscillator, FM pair, and noise generator in addition to the regular oscillators, similar to SynthOne. I do not know if this is even possible with the `Synth` class.

Ultimately, I am trying to create a polyphonic instrument without running, say, 10 different oscillators all at once.

Right now, I am using the following lines of code to attempt changing the waveform, but it seems to have no effect - the `Synth` sounds the same if I remove the code or if I use `.sine`, `.square`, or `.sawtooth`:

```
        self.audio_synth = Synth()
        self.audio_synth.au.setWavetable(Table(.sine).content)

        self.audio_engine.output = self.audio_synth
        try? audio_engine.start()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. A similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080412/audiokit-v5-synth-change-underlying-waveforms) mentioned using `CoreAudio` and a variable called `SynthVoice`, but that went over my head.

Thanks in advance.